# I have data frame and I want to calculate the last three month transaction count and sum for each Group Id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

**Input data set**

| Id | Date | TransAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-02 | 10 |
| A | 2022-01-02 | 20 |
| A | 2022-02-04 | 30 |
| A | 2022-02-05 | 20 |
| A | 2022-04-08 | 300 |
| A | 2022-04-11 | 100 |
| A | 2022-05-13 | 200 |
| A | 2022-06-12 | 20 |
| A | 2022-06-15 | 300 |
| A | 2022-08-16 | 100 |

**Desired output**

| Id | Date | TransAmt | CountThreeMonth | AmountThreeMonths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-02 | 10 | 2 | 30 |
| A | 2022-01-02 | 20 | 2 | 30 |
| A | 2022-02-04 | 30 | 4 | 80 |
| A | 2022-02-05 | 20 | 4 | 80 |
| A | 2022-04-08 | 300 | 4 | 450 |
| A | 2022-04-11 | 100 | 4 | 450 |
| A | 2022-05-13 | 200 | 3 | 600 |
| A | 2022-06-12 | 20 | 5 | 920 |
| A | 2022-06-15 | 300 | 5 | 920 |
| A | 2022-08-16 | 100 | 3 | 420 |

Note: 1. There can be multiple transaction for same date i.e. on  2022-01-02 there are two transaction.
2. I want calculate last 3 months  transaction like- Present Month total Transaction count +  Previous two  month  total Transaction count. Similar logic for amount. like for Jan month only 2 transaction and previous month does not have any transaction so 2 + 0 + 0 =2.
3. I want all calculation for Each group of Id.

Please help me achieve my desired output
Thanking you in Advanced.

Comment: i think last 3 month count of `2022-04-08` is wrong in example output. it must be 4, not 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = [['A', '2022-01-02', 10], ['A', '2022-01-02', 20], ['A', '2022-02-04', 30], 
        ['A', '2022-02-05', 20], ['A', '2022-04-08', 300], ['A', '2022-04-11', 100],
        ['A', '2022-05-13', 200], ['A', '2022-06-12', 20], ['A', '2022-06-15', 300],
        ['A', '2022-08-16', 100], ['B', '2022-01-02', 10], ['B', '2022-01-02', 20],
        ['B', '2022-02-04', 30], ['B', '2022-02-05', 20], ['B', '2022-04-08', 300],
        ['B', '2022-04-11', 100], ['B', '2022-05-13', 200], ['B', '2022-06-12', 20],
        ['B', '2022-06-15', 300], ['B', '2022-08-16', 100]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Id', 'Date', 'TransAmt'])
```

`df1`

```
    Id  Date    TransAmt
0   A   2022-01-02  10
1   A   2022-01-02  20
2   A   2022-02-04  30
3   A   2022-02-05  20
4   A   2022-04-08  300
5   A   2022-04-11  100
6   A   2022-05-13  200
7   A   2022-06-12  20
8   A   2022-06-15  300
9   A   2022-08-16  100
10  B   2022-01-02  10
11  B   2022-01-02  20
12  B   2022-02-04  30
13  B   2022-02-05  20
14  B   2022-04-08  300
15  B   2022-04-11  100
16  B   2022-05-13  200
17  B   2022-06-12  20
18  B   2022-06-15  300
19  B   2022-08-16  100
```

---

**Code**

```
s = df1['Date']
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].astype('Period[M]') 
df2 = df1.groupby(['Id', 'Date'])['TransAmt'].agg(['count', sum])
idx1 = pd.period_range(df1['Date'].min(), df1['Date'].max(), freq='M')
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['Id'].unique(), idx1])
cols = ['Id', 'Date', 'CountThreeMonth', 'AmountofThreeMonth']
n = 3
df3 = df2.reindex(idx2, fill_value=0).groupby(level=0).rolling(n, min_periods=1).sum().droplevel(0).reset_index().set_axis(cols, axis=1)
df1.merge(df3, how='left').assign(Date=s)
```

result(`df1.merge(df3, how='left').assign(Date=s)`)

```
    Id  Date    TransAmt    CountThreeMonth AmountofThreeMonth
0   A   2022-01-02  10      2.0             30.0
1   A   2022-01-02  20      2.0             30.0
2   A   2022-02-04  30      4.0             80.0
3   A   2022-02-05  20      4.0             80.0
4   A   2022-04-08  300     4.0             450.0
5   A   2022-04-11  100     4.0             450.0
6   A   2022-05-13  200     3.0             600.0
7   A   2022-06-12  20      5.0             920.0
8   A   2022-06-15  300     5.0             920.0
9   A   2022-08-16  100     3.0             420.0
10  B   2022-01-02  10      2.0             30.0
11  B   2022-01-02  20      2.0             30.0
12  B   2022-02-04  30      4.0             80.0
13  B   2022-02-05  20      4.0             80.0
14  B   2022-04-08  300     4.0             450.0
15  B   2022-04-11  100     4.0             450.0
16  B   2022-05-13  200     3.0             600.0
17  B   2022-06-12  20      5.0             920.0
18  B   2022-06-15  300     5.0             920.0
19  B   2022-08-16  100     3.0             420.0
```

I'm sorry it's hard to explain

Comment: Good use of `Period[M]`. I was looking for this type. +1 for this.